# Pants are Shaking in Cloth Simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I have some clothes that sew together but whenever the pants sew together, they do this weird jiggly motion, does anyone know how to fix this?

Here is a video of the jiggly motion:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CajLnztSrEL1jao6l-hblUNfQkyLlIaP/view

Comment: Could they be constantly colliding with the leg?

Comment: I am not exactly sure what that means? Do you mean are they going through the leg or are they always touching the leg?

Comment: The latter. Blender does collision work by using an invisible collision barrier, depending on the mesh. If the pants are too close to the mesh it could be that they are at all times touching the collision box and jiggling because of that.

Comment: Have you tried cranking up Damping or Collisions *Impulse Clamping*?